# How to enforce digits only in an xsd simpleType input to CICS/DFHWS2LS - without using the pattern facet element?

Tags: xml, web-services, xsd, cics

As provider of a web service, I'd like to enforce a restriction on the value of an ID field in the associated web request to the expected number of digits, but according to CICS it appears that I'm unable to use a pattern facet element in the xsd/schema for that purpose.  Also, AFAIK the length facet element doesn't support the restriction of characters to digit only.

I've supplied my colleague, a CICS user, with a WSDL file and separate but included xsd file for a web service, and evidently the DFHWS2LS tool in CICS Web Services Assistant does not recognize a pattern facet element contained in the xsd file.

(I know the following - and my colleague has separately confirmed - from the added log print out in my web service code - though the full text of the SOAP request is not available for now, since I have HTTP dump setting turned off in my tomcat start-up script in order to avoid flooding the log file.)

As a result, the web client (presumably COBOL - not sure) generated by my colleague sends to my web service a request whose ID field value is a 255-character (default length) string containing the expected number of digits - but followed by padding blanks - for the ID field.

Here's a sample included schema/xsd - e.g. with ID length 16...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0" targetNamespace="snip1" xmlns:tns="snip2" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="myUpdateStatus" type="tns:myUpdateStatus"/>

  <xs:element name="myUpdateStatusResponse" type="tns:myUpdateStatusResponse"/>

  <xs:complexType name="myUpdateStatus">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="ssn">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base='xs:string'>
<!--            DFHWS2LS ignores the following pattern facet-->
            <xs:pattern value='[0-9]{16}'/>
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="updatedStatus">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:length value="1"/>
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="myUpdateStatusResponse">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="return" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

FYI, I'm not a CICS user; hence I have no vendor support contract. Also, I have yet to inquire whether my colleague's vendor support has a work around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a fixed-length string (`minLength` and `maxLength` having the same values) to shorten up the strings.  In COBOL all strings are fixed-length anyway.

You can use a type of `decimal` with `totalDigits="16"` and `fractionDigits="0"` to enforce the digits-only rule.  The COBOL program will need to be compiled with `ARITH(EXTEND)` and the DFHWS2LS tool will need a control card indicating `WIDE-COMP3=YES`.

This does not solve the problem; it may mitigate it.  The characters `+`, `-`, and `.` are still allowed in the field.

The COBOL program will have a definition for this field that specifies USAGE COMP-3 (packed decimal).

As of this writing, the [documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSGMCP_5.2.0/com.ibm.cics.ts.standards.doc/compliance/XML.html) for the most current version.release of CICS (5.2) indicates DFHWS2LS does not support the pattern facet.

Comment: As I understand it in www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xmlschema-2-20010502, your suggestion would prevent requests with non-decimal values from passing the ensuing schema validation but would still let pass the non-digit characters (+_.) as well as optional - hence excluded - leading zeroes, e.g., requested parameter values such as "+1.", true?

Comment: @cbAtMethods4so I believe you are correct.  So this doesn't get you to digits only, it merely gets rid of alphabetic and most special characters.  Closer to what you want, but still not quite there.

Comment: Is(are) there any version(s) of WSA/DFHWS2LS that will support/recognize said pattern facet?

Comment: @cbAtMethods4so It appears not: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSGMCP_5.2.0/com.ibm.cics.ts.standards.doc/compliance/XML.html indicates the pattern facet is ignored in the most recent release of CICS and its tools (DFHWS2LS is one of those tools).